# Where can I find Simulink Projects?

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink

Can anyone suggest me a site where I may found some basic projects for Matlab simulation. Thesis prjoects etc. Basically I need to understand best practices. I'm beginner and could not understand too much big projects online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't specific about what you're really looking for, but if you're looking for basic "how to" info, then the getting started guide is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/getting-started-with-simulink.html), and a basic example of constructing a model is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/gs/create-a-simple-model.html).

There are also some other basic examples [here](http://www.goddardconsulting.ca/software-tutorials.html#Simulink)

Comment: i'm looking projects of Graduated students. That what level of projects they develop. Then some good projects (professionals).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are looking for, but maybe here:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/index?term=type%3AModel